# Can we use datatable jquery in reactJS application instead of using react-data-table-component - package

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I'm new to reactJS. I would like to use Jquery Datatable in my react web application. A few concerns like How healthy is using jquery in ReactJs? Is it possible to use Jquery DataTable directly?

Comment: It might be possible I guess but definitely not going to be an easy integration, nor recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** use Jquery but **it's not suggested**! You have everything in javascript so mixing JS and Jquery just makes your application complicated and possibly buggy!
If you think you need jquery it means your design and pattern in react is wrong!

Comment: You did not answered his question